# vue-test-utils how to use trigger's options

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I want to test `el-button` if it can change to the correct view by `$router`,but I am confused weather the `trigger` supportted cause i find this in its document

> The `trigger` method takes an `optional` options object. The properties in
>   the options object are added to the Event.
>
> Note that target cannot be added in the `options` object.

```
const wrapper = mount(MyButton)
wrapper.trigger('click', { 
    button: 0
})
```

but failed and i get this info

> TypeError: Cannot set property type of [object Event] which has only a
>   getter
>
> ```
>   65 |     // expect(mockFn).toBeCalled
>   66 |     // expect(mockFn).toBeCalledTimes(1)
>   67 |     wrapper.find(ElementUI.Button).trigger('click', {
>      |                                    ^
>   68 |       id: 1,
>   69 |       type: 'view'
>   70 |     })
> ```

vue file

```
<el-button
    plain
    type="primary"
    @click="changeView(-1, 'edit')">
    newPicture
</el-button>
```

js

```
changeView(id, type) {
    if (type === 'view') {
       this.$router.push({ path: './detail', query: { id, type }})
     } else if (type === 'edit') {
       this.$router.push({ path: './edit', query: { id, type }})
     }
},
```

And I want to write a test file for this button

```
   ...
    it('add button click', () => {
        const mockFn = jest.fn()
        wrapper.setMethods({
            changeView: mockFn
        })
        wrapper.find(ElementUI.Button).trigger('click', {
            id: 1,
            type: 'view'
        })
        wrapper.update()
        expect(mockFn).toBeCalled
        console.log(wrapper.vm.$route.path)
   })
  ...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the options your passing are js $event properties. here's a list of them: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp

when you trigger that click event, the `changeView` will be called, with the parameters you passed to it(-1 and 'edit'). they are not event properties and you dont pass them as options. so your test whould look like:

```
  it('add button click', () => {
        const mockFn = jest.fn()
        wrapper.setMethods({
            changeView: mockFn
        })
        wrapper.find(ElementUI.Button).trigger('click');
        wrapper.update();
        expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith(-1,'edit');
   })
```